# PostgreSQL in Helm: initdbScripts Parameter

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The default Helm Chart for PostgreSQL (i.e. `stable/postgresql`) defines an `initdbScripts` parameter that allows initialization scripts to be run. However, I can't seem to get the format correct on how to issue it via the command line.

**Could someone provide an example of how to populate this command line parameter?**

Here's what I'm issuing, minus a working version of the `initdbScripts` parameter.

```
helm install stable/postgresql -n testpg \
    --set global.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase=testpg \
    --set global.postgresql.postgresqlUsername=testpg \
    --set global.postgresql.postgresqlPassword=testpg \
    --set global.postgresql.servicePort=5432 \
    --set initdbScripts=(WHAT GOES HERE TO RUN "sql/init.sql"??) \
    --set service.type=LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [stable/postgresql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) helm chart, `initdbScripts` is a dictionary of init script names which are multi-line variables:

> ```
> ## initdb scripts
> ## Specify dictionary of scripts to be run at first boot
> ## Alternatively, you can put your scripts under the files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory
> ##
> # initdbScripts:
> #   my_init_script.sh:|
> #      #!/bin/sh
> #      echo "Do something."
> ```

Let's assume that we have the following `init.sql` script:

```
CREATE USER helm;
CREATE DATABASE helm;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE helm TO helm;
```

When we are going to inject a multi-line text into values we need to deal with indentation in YAML.

For above particular case it is:

```
helm install stable/postgresql -n testpg \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase=testpg \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlUsername=testpg \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlPassword=testpg \
--set global.postgresql.servicePort=5432 \
--set initdbScripts."init\.sql"="CREATE USER helm;
CREATE DATABASE helm;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE helm TO helm;" \
--set service.type=LoadBalancer
```

There is some explanation to above example:

1. If script's name has `.` it should be escaped, like `"init\.sql"`.
2. Script's content is in double quotes, because it's multi-line string variable.

Comment: extra thanks for mentioning escaping the "." in the key name, e.g. `init\.sql`

Answer (score 5):

Here's what @nickgryg's answer looks like with `values.yaml` instead of command line switches.

```
primary:
  initdb:
    scripts:
      init.sql: |
        CREATE USER helm;
        CREATE DATABASE helm;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE helm TO helm;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use some sort of templating/replacements with that? Let's say, if using helm secrets and you want to set the password with the user?

Comment: @McFlurriez I had similer thoughts since I wanted to use Hashicorp Vault for secrets. I include the password during helm install: "helm install postgresql . --namespace foo --set global.postgresql.auth.password=`kubectl exec --namespace foo vault-0 -- vault kv get -field=password secret/db-pass`"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "hashicorp/helm" provider on terraform you can use something like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "postgres" {
  name      = "postgres"
  chart     = "bitnami/postgresql"
  version   = "13.2.0"
  set {
    name  = "primary.initdb.scripts"
    value = "init_dbs.sql: CREATE USER my_user; CREATE DATABASE my_db; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO my_user;"
  }
}
```