# How to init several PostgreSQL DBs on bare metal Kubernetes via Helm

Tags: bash, postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create several databases after installation of Helm chart **bitnami/postgresql**. I added setting **initdbScripts** into helm install command:

```
helm install postgresql bitnami/postgresql --namespace=namespace_name \
    --set global.postgresql.postgresqlUsername=username,global.postgresql.postgresqlPassword=password123 \
    --set initdbScripts."init\.sql"="CREATE DATABASE db1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db1 TO username;
CREATE DATABASE db2;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db2 TO username;
CREATE DATABASE db3;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db3 TO username;"
```

The pod starts failing with CrashLoopBackOff, and there's a line in the log:
`touch: cannot touch '/bitnami/postgresql/.user_scripts_initialized': Permission denied`

My assumption why it does not work is that I have installed the chart to a bare-metal cluster and since it has no dynamic provisioning set up, I created a volume first:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgresql-data
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgresql
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: postgresql-data
spec:
  storageClassName: postgresql-data
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/postgresql-data"
```

The volume is successfully claimed by PVC which I don't create manually.

Is there a way to initialize several databases using initdbScripts on a BM Kubernetes cluster? Any bare SQL or combined with Bash script solution would work.

**Version of Helm and Kubernetes**:
*helm version:*

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}
```

*kubectl version:*

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:26:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:39:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

My solution is based on the best response in this thread: [PostgreSQL in Helm: initdbScripts Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499984/postgresql-in-helm-initdbscripts-parameter)

Comment: Please share more info about your kubernetes cluster. Is it a simple single-node cluster like Minikube or it contains more nodes ? How are you going to achive `ReadWriteMany` access mode using `hostPath` ? Such volueme cannot be mounted by many nodes so only `ReadWriteOnce` will work. Could you `ls -ld /bitnami/postgresql` ? What are the permissions and owner of this directory ?